# MSSQL: equalize counting-values with missing zeros

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using a CRM-Software on which several thousand customers have been imported from another program a few years ago.

Now I noticed that I missed a zero-digit in one field while importing, causing newly added addresses to appear last in list, when they should be first.
To visualize the problem, here is the (shortened) schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS
    ([customerid] varchar(20), [addressno] varchar(20), [name] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO ADDRESS
    ([customerid], [addressno], [name])
VALUES
    ('5705', '5705-01', 'John Doe'),
    ('5705', '5705-001', 'Jane Doe'),
    ('5705', '5705-002', 'Smith'),
    ('5705', '5705-003', 'Alice'),
    ('5706', '5706-01', 'Bob'),
    ('5707', '5707-001', 'Carol'),
    ('5707', '5707-002', 'Chuck')
;
```

As you can see, some `addressno` values only have 2 digits (+ "customerid-") - these are the imported ones, and the new ones have 3 digits.

What I need to accomplish is to add the missing zero, and if more entries by that `customerid` exist their value should increase, so the goal would be this result:

```
    ('5705', '5705-001', 'John Doe'),  /* Added a zero */
    ('5705', '5705-002', 'Jane Doe'),  /* Increased number */
    ('5705', '5705-003', 'Smith'),     /* Increased number */
    ('5705', '5705-004', 'Alice'),     /* Increased number */
    ('5706', '5706-001', 'Bob'),       /* Added a zero */
    ('5707', '5707-001', 'Carol'),     /* No change */
    ('5707', '5707-002', 'Chuck')      /* No change */
```

This runs on Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I would like to write a solution in SQL so i can run it within SQL Management Studio, this seems to be the easiest way.

Sadly, my SQL knowledge is pretty basic, I really have no idea where to start, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, if addressno represents an index in the list, it should be an int, not a varchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want. I'm assuming that the character lengths you've shown are fixed and it's safe to re-derive the left-hand side of the `addressno` from the `customerid`:

```
declare @ADDRESS table
    ([customerid] varchar(20), [addressno] varchar(20), [name] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @ADDRESS
    ([customerid], [addressno], [name])
VALUES
    ('5705', '5705-01', 'John Doe'),
    ('5705', '5705-001', 'Jane Doe'),
    ('5705', '5705-002', 'Smith'),
    ('5705', '5705-003', 'Alice'),
    ('5706', '5706-01', 'Bob'),
    ('5707', '5707-001', 'Carol'),
    ('5707', '5707-002', 'Chuck')

; With Extracts as (
    select *,
        CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(addressno,6,3)) as rn,
        CASE WHEN LEN(addressno)=7 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as series
    from
        @ADDRESS
), newnumbers as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY series,rn) as row
    from Extracts
)
update newnumbers
set addressno =
    customerid + '-' +
    RIGHT('000'+CONVERT(varchar(20),row),3)

select * from @ADDRESS
```

Result:

```
customerid           addressno            name
-------------------- -------------------- ------------
5705                 5705-001             John Doe
5705                 5705-002             Jane Doe
5705                 5705-003             Smith
5705                 5705-004             Alice
5706                 5706-001             Bob
5707                 5707-001             Carol
5707                 5707-002             Chuck
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much for this really fast answer! I will try it out tomorrow night and of course accept your answer if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY name ) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS rn
               FROM     dbo.ADDRESS
             )
UPDATE cte SET addressno = CAST(customerid AS VARCHAR(20)) + '-' + 
                           REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(rn)) + rn
```

Probably `( PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY name )` you want to replace this with `( PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY AddressID )`

Comment: Ordering by name doesn't seem to be indicated. Ordering by (I assume you mean) `Addressno` also doesn't fit, as is, since that would be a textual ordering placing `5705-01` later than `5705-002`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I had mentioned that he should order by AddressID

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution.

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #address([customerid] varchar(20), [addressno] varchar(20), [name] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #address ([customerid], [addressno], [name])
VALUES
    ('5705', '5705-01', 'John Doe'),
    ('5705', '5705-001', 'Jane Doe'),
    ('5705', '5705-002', 'Smith'),
    ('5705', '5705-003', 'Alice'),
    ('5706', '5706-01', 'Bob'),
    ('5707', '5707-001', 'Carol'),
    ('5707', '5707-002', 'Chuck')
;

-- Original Output
SELECT * FROM #address

-- Output of what is updated
SELECT *,SUBSTRING(addressno,1,PATINDEX(N'%-%',addressno)-1) + N'-' +RIGHT(N'000'+
    CONVERT(nvarchar(100),CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(addressno,PATINDEX(N'%-%',addressno)+1,LEN(addressno))) < 3 
        THEN SUBSTRING(addressno,PATINDEX(N'%-%',addressno)+1,LEN(addressno)) 
        ELSE SUBSTRING(addressno,PATINDEX(N'%-%',addressno)+1,LEN(addressno)) +1 
    END),3) 
FROM #address

-- Here is the work done! Update everything with the correct pattern.
UPDATE #address
set addressno = SUBSTRING(addressno,1,PATINDEX(N'%-%',addressno)-1) + N'-' +RIGHT(N'000'+
    CONVERT(nvarchar(100),CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(addressno,PATINDEX(N'%-%',addressno)+1,LEN(addressno))) < 3 
        THEN SUBSTRING(addressno,PATINDEX(N'%-%',addressno)+1,LEN(addressno)) 
        ELSE SUBSTRING(addressno,PATINDEX(N'%-%',addressno)+1,LEN(addressno)) +1 
    END),3) 

-- Show changes
SELECT * FROM #address

-- Cleanup!
DROP TABLE #address
```

Just the update is the necessary part.

Comment: Jane Doe is meant to be renumbered from `5705-001` to `5705-002` (and similarly for Smith and Alice)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE  @ADDRESS TABLE
    ([customerid] varchar(20), [addressno] varchar(20), [name] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @ADDRESS
    ([customerid], [addressno], [name])
VALUES
    ('5705', '5705-01', 'John Doe'),
    ('5705', '5705-001', 'Jane Doe'),
    ('5705', '5705-002', 'Smith'),
    ('5705', '5705-003', 'Alice'),
    ('5706', '5706-01', 'Bob'),
    ('5707', '5707-001', 'Carol'),
    ('5707', '5707-002', 'Chuck')

;

select [customerid], SUBSTRING([addressno],0,CHARINDEX('-',[addressno]))+ 
'-' 
+RIGHT('00000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([addressno]),0,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE([addressno]))))),3), 
[name] from @ADDRESS
```

Comment: Jane Doe is meant to be renumbered from `5705-001` to `5705-002` (and similarly for Smith and Alice)